# Wordpress users in database but not showing in admin

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I migrated a wordpress site to a new server I copied all the files and plugins etc but I had registered users that I created using Ultimate Member plugin. I tried to export/import this users with plugins but didnt have any success so I copied all the data from the old wordpress user table to the new one and from the old usersmeta table to the new one but the users dont show in the admin of the new wordpress site.

Le site c'est www.medicitus.com

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the wp_ table prefix is correct
2. $WPUserID is just created User ID from wp_users table
3. $WPUserLogin is just created User Login from wp_users table

Comment: I am sure that the wp_ table prefix is correct because there's where my admin was but I dont understand what you mean by points 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple plugin like all in one migration. Make an export file and import in new wordpress install on your new URL

Comment: Any plugin you recomend? I tried several but none worked. I think it might have to do with the fact that my users have like 40 fields of metadata attached

Comment: all-in-one-migration plugin by ServMask. It moves the files and database for you. Hustle free. it is also free from the WP repo